# Is there any advantage to a metal plaster hawk?

Tags: plaster

### Background

I am a plastering novice (mainly an IT guy) and, while I am up for trying my hand at anything, I do not intend to become a professional plasterer. That said, I am very much of the opinion that one should purchase the best tools possible so that they last more than one lifetime - I want to hand my tools down to my kids.

I currently have this.

*Draper 40938 ABS Plasterers Hawk, 330mm x 330mm*

[image: Draper 40938 ABS Plasterers Hawk, 330mm x 330mm]

Subsequently to purchasing the Draper hawk, I have now seen that Ox do an Aluminium hawk.

*OX OX-P010513 Plaster Hawk 330mm×330mm - Aluminum Plastering Hawk with Soft Grip Handle*

[image: OX OX-P010513 Plaster Hawk 330mm×330mm - Aluminum Plastering Hawk with Soft Grip Handle]

I am led to believe that Ox are arguably the leaders in the plastering tools market, while Draper, again arguably, aim more at making cheaper tools for DIYers.

### Questions

What objective differences are there between a plastic hawk and a metal one?

Comment: A metal one might survive abuse better(falling from 20ft, being step on), but think it mainly comes down to which one you like working with better.

Comment: As they say, "The best tool is the one you actually use."

Comment: You *already own* the plastic one and you *don't need two.* Wooden ones were common back in the day...they all hold plaster. Which is all they need to do.

Comment: Aluminum might be lighter so less fatigue.

Comment: I've never seen a mason use a plastic hawk, nor one with a good handle that wasn't aluminum. All that really matters is which has a better handle. On the Ox, there's a half inch of neoprene to rest your thumb on. On the crappy one there's just plastic, with splines in the way as a bonus.